# combine multiple csv files with different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a requirement to combine multiple csv files into one single file.
Challenge is :- All these csv files differ in the number of columns present in them.
So I was thinking if there is any way to read all the column names from these files and then while combining these csv files , I can read the respective column name from the incoming file , match it with the column name from the big combined file and accordingly save the value. In case the column name is not found , then store N/A or null in the combined file.

Does it look feasible or any other better approach ?

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading CSV files into pandas DataFrames. Then you can combine them by using `concat`. Let's say you have two pandas dataframes, df1 and df2. This code will combine them and leaves NaN when it is not applicable:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [1,2],
                    'column2': [3,4],
                    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [5,6],
                    'column3': [7,8],
                    })
pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
```

Output is like this:

```
   column1  column2  column3
0        1      3.0      NaN
1        2      4.0      NaN
2        5      NaN      7.0
3        6      NaN      8.0
```

Comment: does this mean that I should write down all the columns? Is there any way to just import the CSV file and panda can detect the columns itself?

Comment: No, you should not write down all columns. That was just a toy example. If your data is in a csv file, you can read it and load it into a Pandas dataframe by ```df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv') ```

Comment: Thanks @amin-gheibi. I think I can pass sequence of DaraFrame objects to the concat function. I just need to use glob library to read all the csv files name.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using [miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It's a tool for working with CSV data. You can install it using brew, choco or yum and then head to the directory that your files exist. Then use the command below to save the result in *result.csv* file.

```
mlr --csv reshape -r "^A" -o item,value then reshape -s item,value \ then unsparsify --fill-with "" *.csv > result.csv
```

Some notes about the command:

- reshape -r "^A" -o item,value, to transform the input CSVs from wide to long, applying this to all the fields whose name begins with "A";
- reshape -s item,value, to transform the previous output from long to wide;
- unsparsify --fill-with "", to manage field names over all input records. For field names absent in a given record but present in others, fills in the value "";